# Does LayoutInflater work with a layout xml file that uses includes?

Tags: android, android-layout

Here's the rub:  I have a layout that uses the include tag.  The layout is simple ->

```
<LinearLayout>
  <TextView ...>

  <LinearLayout>
     <include ...>
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now the included file is nothing more than:

```
<LinearLayout>
  <TextView ... android:id="@+id/inner_text">
</LinearLayout>
```

Now, if I try to access the TextView inner_text in either the create or onStart call, it throws a NPE.  I have tried using LayoutInflater to infate the included xml file and then access inner_text but to no avail - it always fails.

So, the question is :  does LayoutInflater work with included xml files of the parent xml file?  What I would like to do is grab the contents of the included xml file - and set the whole thing to be either visible or not visible based on preferences.

Nothing seems to allow me to grab the TextView object.

Now, when I include the xml as just a nested element in the parent file (not using the include tag) - then it accesses that LinearLayout just fine - but that defeats my purpose of trying to make the layout of the view dynamic - that is, I can change the contents of the child included layout at will - and not have to do any changes to the parent layout.

Any help, pointers, suggestions -> greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As suggestion I think you can have in the main xml some Layout component left empty, them in runtime, inflate the main xml, then the included xml and add the content of the included in the space you left in the main.

But I think you example have to work, internally the Android uses the inflater to inflate resources. Can you edit and tell a bit more? Code examples can be helpfully.

Answer (score 0):

well, very strange, when you inflate a view from any xml resource (if xml resources have or have not nested resources with include) the view must hold all the parsed xml. So, yes,  LayoutInflater work with included xml files of the parent xml file.

i copied here the way i'm doing now...

my generic layout (a header with text, progress bar and image)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/genericHeaderLogoPin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_pin"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/genericHeaderTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/genericHeaderLogoPin"
        android:textSize="18dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#FF0C9994"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/genericHeaderProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="25dip"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/genericHeaderLogoPin"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Inverse"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

my parent layout... include the generic layout and a ListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="@drawable/background_new_search_activity_1">

    <include layout="@layout/generic_header_layout" android:id="@+id/listaBusquedasHeader"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

my onCreate method that inflate the parent layout mentioned above:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_busquedas_activity, null);

        setContentView(view);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(listItemClickListener);

        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.genericHeaderTitle)).setText(R.string.messagesActivityTitle);
    }
```

and that´s all, i hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx for the help - I discovered what my problem was - I was trying to inflate the included file - not the parent container - so that's why it never found the elements.  I wish the documentation would have mentioned that - logically I would think the parent xml file would load - but the included files may need inflating - guess not.

Works now thanks to your code examples you submitted.

Thanx.